# How to get all the likes of a twitter user using tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy with 1.1 API and Elevated access.

I have been trying to request all the likes of a user but there seems to be a limit of about 1430 returned tweets. I've tried with a couple of test accounts and it seems to get 1430-1440 then a "Too Many Requests - Rate limit exceeded" error is returned.

This is the call:
tweepy.Cursor( api.get_favorites, screen_name=twitterUsername ).items( 3000 )

When I call rate_limit_status() the only out of limits value is '/favorites/list', but the limit appears to be 75:
Limit:75 Remaining: 0 Reset: {timestamp for 15 minutes later}.

Frustratingly, initially the rate limit seemed to be more generous (over 2500 tweets were returned)

Is there a way to work with Twitter's limits so that I can have access and work with all the likes of a user?

Or at least is there a way to ask for the likes before a certain date?

Answer (score 1):

Pay careful attention to the word "rate" in that diagnostic.
It refers to "records per hour",
rather than "total number of records".

Twitter offer extensive documentation on this topic:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits#recovering

You obtained a `429` status because you ignored the
rate limit. Just sleep() a bit between requests.
Code that does a one-off query and fails to sleep
will more likely trigger a rate error
when querying *many* records back-to-back
than when querying *few* records.

Consider using the excellent [tenacity](https://pypi.org/project/tenacity/) back-off / retry library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm not sure how to combine sleeping with the big api.get_favorites request. If I hit the limit and sleep, when I rerun the request I will get the same results (tweets starting from today and arranged according to descending date). The earliest tweets are not returned. Is there some way to request them? Or pickup where we left off before sleeping?